# Adding second domain to LAMP stack

Tags: apache, web-services, ubuntu, lamp

I currently have one domain set up on my LAMP server, and I want to add another one. I tried doing it myself but when I ran into issues, I follow [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts). I had example.com set up and it was working fine, all traffic would redirect to its https and I want to continue that.

However, the second domain I'm using (represented by test.ca) is still going to example.com. I was hoping someone could inform me what I am doing wrong. Should test.ca be a folder within example.com? and how do you point to it? Is it cause I redirect traffic to https://example.com for the ssl so all traffic just goes there?

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.ca
    Redirect permanent / http://test.ca
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/example.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/intermediate.crt

    ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/example.com/logs/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html/example.com/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
    ServerName test.ca
    ServerAlias www.test.ca
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test.ca/public_html/
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/test.ca/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/test.ca/logs/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html/test.ca/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/example.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/intermediate.crt

    ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/example.com/logs/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html/example.com/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/test.ca.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.ca
    Redirect permanent / http://test.ca
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:444>
    ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
    ServerName test.ca
    ServerAlias www.test.ca
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test.ca/public_html/
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/test.ca/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/test.ca/logs/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html/test.ca/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the header of the Virtualhost from

```
<VirtualHost *:444>
```

to

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
```

as a start, or it must be your intentions to link to that port instead of the default https port.

Comment: I've updated it to be 443 instead of 444. Now I get this error:    `script '/var/www/html/test.ca/public_html/httptest.php' not found or unable to stat
` which I found [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/185954/hosts-file-entries-for-multiple-domains-on-vps) but it does not help much. Ever seen this?

Comment: Does apache return this? Make sure the file /var/www/html/test.ca/public_html/httptest.php exists and the right permissions

Comment: Yes apache returns it. My first domain, example.com does not have this file and it still works. Whats the purpose?

Comment: As far as I know this file has no default purpose. You might browse your apache config file to search for a link to 'httptest.php', maybe you set the default index file to 'httptest.php' even tough you stated you don't need it for your first domain. If this is not the problem I suggest you open a new question with this new problem and close this question by accepting the answer.

Comment: yeah there is no "httptest.php" in the apache2.conf or "httptest"